# Разбор указателей

Tags: golang

Не могу разобраться в указателях, есть код

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    p0 := new(int)
    fmt.Println(p0)
    fmt.Println(*p0)


    x := *p0
    p1, p2 := &x, &x
    fmt.Println(p1 == p2) // true
    fmt.Println(p0 == p1) // false
    fmt.Println(p0 == p2) // false

    p3 := &*p0
    fmt.Println(p3)
    fmt.Println(p0 == p3) // true
    *p0, *p1 = 123, 789
    fmt.Println(*p2, x, *p3) // 789 789 123

    fmt.Printf("%T, %T \n", *p0, x) // int, int
    fmt.Printf("%T, %T \n", p0, p1) // *int, *int
}
```

Итак в строке

1. `x := *p` у нас лежит копия *p, 0
2. `p1, p2 := &x, &x`, у нас адрес на x
3. теперь самое непонятное `p3 := &*p0`, что тут вообще произошло?
4. `p0 == p3` почему это true

Так же в учебнике встретил такие конструкции:

```
*&a++
*&*&a++
**&p++
*&*p++
```

это нормальный код?

Answer (score 2):

Не зная голанга, можно рассмотреть такие общечеловеческие соображения:

```
p0 := new(int)
```

Выделена память под целое число, **указатель** на неё хранится в указательной переменной `p0` (пусть это адрес `0x44444444`). Возможно,  подразумевается инициализация нулями (спецификацию языка я не смотрел, может быть мусор). Само целое число по данному адресу не имеет своей личной целочисленной переменной, оно безымянно.

```
x := *p0
```

Указатель **разыменован** - содержимое по адресу памяти `0x44444444`  - 4 байта (целое в голанге 32-х битное?) - интерпретируется как целое число, и записывается в переменную `x`. Значение пока совпадает с безымянным значением (да, является копией).

```
p1 := &x
```

**Адрес** переменной `x` записан в `p1`, этот адрес **другой**, скажем, `0x44444448`

Область памяти, начиная с адреса `0x44444444`

```
00  00  00  00  |  00  00  00  00
 --------------------------------
  noname= 00    |  x= 00
```

.

```
 p3 := &*p0
```

Переменная разыменована, но в результат взят опять адрес, куда она указывала, т.е. реально произошло копирование указателя `p0` в указатель `p3`, там всё то же `0x44444444`

```
*p0, *p1 = 123, 789
```

По адресу безымянной переменной записано 123, а по адресу `x` записано 789. Мы помним, что эти адреса разные. Теперь в области памяти, начиная с адреса `0x44444444`, хранится

```
7B  00  00  00  |  15  03  00  00
 --------------------------------
  noname=123    |  x=789
```

т.е. значение `x` больше не является копией

Про конструкции из учебника `*&a++` это взятие адреса, разыменование, инкремент (т.е. `a += 1`) (++ особый оператор, см. описание приоритетов). Это более логичная конструкция, чем разыменование+взятие адреса (в других языках на промежуточных этапах можно привести тип к другому).

Если сделать

```
a := 3;
p := &a;
```

И применить любую из конструкций, то `a` станет равно 4.
Код ненормальный ;)

Comment: получается тут x := *p0 копия числа без адреса, а в p3 := &*p0 копия с адресом?

Comment: В общем - да, в x0 копия значения, в p3 копия адреса

Comment: ясно спасибо, странно конечно, если в одну строку разыменование с указателем то копируем значение и адрес значения

Comment: Ну это неестественный код, чтобы запутать. Про конструкции из учебника *&a++ это взятие адреса, разыменование, инкремент (т.е. `a += 1`). Это более логичная конструкция, чем разыменование+взятие адреса.

Comment: @Вячеслав Вопрос решён? Знаете о принятии ответов галочкой?